# Dynamic List position

Tags: python, robotframework

I'm trying to dynamically access a value in a list.
I have a parameter ${tblid} that I receive from a SQL query and I want to use it to extract a specific value from a list called @{ColNames}.

When I create a variable with the `Set Variable` keyword, I can do the following:

```
${INTEGER} =    Set Variable    0
Log @{ColNames}[${INTEGER}]
```

I've tried the following things:

```
Log @{ColNames}[${tblid}]

${INTEGER} =    Evaluate    ${tblid}
Log @{ColNames}[${INTEGER}]

${INTEGER} =    Convert To Integer  ${tblid}
Log @{ColNames}[${INTEGER}]
```

All three attempts return a "Non-existing variable" error.
I had a feeling that it might have to do with the data type (?) that the query returns and that's why I attempted to use `Convert To Integer` but now I'm just not sure.

Any ideas?

Comment: I removed the sql tag.  I don't think this has anything to do with SQL (other than that being the source of the string).

Comment: Hope you're right. I was debating it and decided to add it since a regular variable does work and only a variable coming from the query doesn't. But if you think it's irrelevant, then I'm fine with it. :-)

Comment: . . This is not a *generic* SQL question.  It might be related to how you are accessing a particular database, in which case the tag for the database *would* be appropriate (sqlite, mysql, sql-server, oracle, postgres, etc.).

Comment: it's... not a Python question either, is it?

Comment: What is `${tblid}`? If you're getting an error, it must be that it's not an integer. Can you provide an actual, complete error message?

Comment: ${tblid} is a value I get from a SQL query. It is a number but it might not recognize it as an integer. That's why I tried using Convert To Integer but it didn't help. This is the error I receive: Non-existing variable '@{ColNames}[${tblId}]'

Comment: There must be more you're not sharing with us. If `${tblid}` does actually represent an integer, and `@{ColNames}` does actually represent an array, your code _will_ work. Without us seeing what's in `@{ColNames}` and what's actually in `${tblid}` it's impossible for us to accurately guess.